# How to specify an `@since` for a method alias?

Tags: ruby, documentation, yard

I am writing a Ruby gem. To document my code, I am using [YARD](https://yardoc.org/). I have been using `@since` (see [here](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md)) to mark in which gem versions methods have been added. However, I'm having a problem. In one version of my gem I had defined a method. Now, *in a new version of the gem*, I want to define an alias for that method. How, with YARD/RDoc, can I add `@since` to an `alias`?

I have tried this, which didn't work:

```rb
# ...
# @since 1.0.0
def my_method
  # ...
end
# @since 1.1.0
alias new_method my_method
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't seem possible, unless you define two separate methods. I would avoid using `@since` in the docs, since docs are versioned as well.

Comment: @DannyB Interesting. What do you mean by "I would avoid using `@since` in the docs, since docs are versioned as well"? What is `@since` intended for?

Comment: Well - `@since` was designed for what you are trying to use it for, but if you start tagging each method since when it was introduced, you will spend way too much time on docs, with questionable benefits. See [this](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/kojo/0.3.6/Kojo/Template) for example - notice the version number is in the URL. Your docs and README should assume users are using the latest version, if not, they can always see older versions that matches their version.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [`@!method`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#method) directive to accomplish this:

```
# @since 1.0.0
def my_method
  # ...
end

# @!method new_method
#   @since 1.1.0
alias new_method my_method
```

Comment: This is an interesting possibility, but it does not seem to work. The new method is simply ignore and instead still shown as "also known as..."